# Firebase Remote Config long request response time issue

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-remote-config

We use in our application Firebase Remote Config, because we want to have all configuration variables fetched before app starts (it is crucial for us) we added 'extended splash' screen to our app. 
Case is, that in situations where it is fresh app launch or we updated app from App Store (which don't have Firebase configured) with version with Firebase, request for remote config (`remoteConfig.fetch(withExpirationDuration:)`) takes something around ~3 sec, there was also situations where request takes ~8 sec...

We tested,that the same request on Android at each time we try took ~1 sec.

Whether someone has the same problem? Those additional ~3 sec added to app launch time are very painful for us.

We looked into requests traffic and we noticed on iOS that there is 3 more request related with Firebase before request for Remote Config values (we suppose that those request are embedded into serial queue).

---

Please bear in mind that we perform test without Firebase `developer` mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For fast response, you can use Firebase database. 
Remote config isn't designed for fast response.