# Firebase Remote Config fetch duration

Tags: firebase, firebase-remote-config

We are consistently seeing anywhere from 6 to 25 seconds to fetch remote config on good internet connections. Is this normal or are we doing something wrong? We initialize our app as soon as it starts. We tested both in Europe and US.

Comment: Today I also suffered with the fact that if you clear the application data, then the request to pull the config takes about 9 seconds. If this is the second launch of the application, then somewhere around 3-5 seconds. And if you press the Refresh button from a running application, then 1 second. I was angry for a long time and did not understand why it was so, I got a bug from testing that, after clearing the cache, it takes too long to load the config. Apparently they did not check on the emulator.

Comment: But on my phone, the config always loads in 1 second. I checked my colleagues on the phone and the same thing, everything is fast. While I closed the question for myself without understanding the exact reason. Try also not on emulators or other devices

Comment: I am experiencing same problem on Android Studio's Emulator (Android 12, Pixel 4). It basically takes around 1.5 minute to do the backend fetch. Seems like Google servers are rate limiting it? `fetchTimeoutInSeconds` setting does not have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

There is already a same question.

> [Firebase Remote Config long request response time issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46071648/firebase-remote-config-long-request-response-time-issue?rq=4)

While it's possible to use Firebase Realtime database for fast response, there is also a [recommended strategy](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/loading):

**Strategy 3**: Load new values for next startup
An effective strategy is to load new configuration values to activate on your app's next startup. In this strategy, your app activates fetched values on startup before attempting to fetch new ones, operating on the assumption that it may have already fetched — but not yet activated — new configuration values. The order of operations for this strategy is:

On startup, immediately activate previously fetched values. This applies any values you've downloaded from the server in a previous session, and is nearly instantaneous.
While the user interacts with your app, kick off an asynchronous call to fetch new values according to the default minimum fetch interval and add a real-time config update listener. The real-time listener will automatically fetch any values that are published on the server while your app is running. Real-time updates bypass the minimum fetch interval setting.
In the completion handler or callback for the fetch call, do nothing. Your app will keep the downloaded values until you activate them the next time the app starts.
With this strategy, user wait time is greatly minimized. Combining the fetch and real-time listener strategies with activate() calls as needed in the app lifecycle makes sure users have the latest values from Remote Config as they interact with your app.

*Tip: Use `fetch()` and `addOnConfigUpdateListener()` as complementary methods. It's recommended to call fetch once per app launch, then start listening for updates in real time and activate them as needed. Listening for real-time updates makes it possible to get the latest parameter values without calling fetch frequently.*

It's also possible to decrease the fetching time reducing the amount of data.